# How to access the corresponding Node a controller is attached to

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

For a given controller is there anyway built-in way to access the node that controller is "attached" to without having to give it a FXML ID and specific annotation? I can't find anything relevant to this in [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) or searching online.

For example, how do I access the HBox from org.example.FooController

```
<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.FooController">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

For now I've just been giving the node a FXML ID of "root" and then using the following in my controller, but it feels like I'm missing a trick...

```
@FXML
private Node root
```

Comment: What about calling `FXMLLoader.getRoot()` after loading the FXML File?

Comment: In my setup the FXMLLoader call is external to the controllers, but yes, I could pass that into the controller after I've created it, I'm surprised there isn't some default way of doing this though...

Comment: You do not have to set the root in the FXMLLoader. You can just load an FXML and retrieve its root afterwards with the method.

Comment: I think the OP is looking to access the root node in the *controller*. Typically the `FXMLLoader` is not accessible in the controller; so to use your suggestion he would have to pass the root node into the controller from the place where the FXML is loaded - that ends up being just as much boilerplate code as setting an `fx:id` on the root.

Comment: Yes, I read the question again.. I was too fast again :-/

Comment: There's no trick, the way you are doing it is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consensus appears to be there is no magic way to do this if your controller is nested or not involved in the loading process.

I've been sticking to the convention of fx:id of "root", and matching @FXML

```
@FXML
private Node root
```